# Android Get Json Data in a Loop Failed when JSON array is Empty

Tags: java, android, json, service

I followed [This](https://androidjson.com/save-store-php-mysql-json-parsing-data-sqlite/) to Get JSON data and Save In SQLite

So Here I will Get 10 to 100 Records per every 5 min So I have added the Same Functionality to a Service and that Service Repeats every 5min

So Here Now Problem Is that It will get Data for some Records.. after some Records like 15-20 Its showing this Error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`

This Repeats for Every 5 Min in that for Example I am Getting 30 Records in that atleast 5 time its showing This error...

Due to This I am loosing that Record data.. Due to this I am not Able to get 30 Records from server what ever are missing its gone...

How to get of the This error

This is my Service Class.....

```
    public class ServMain2 extends Service {

    public static final String MyShredPrefs = "MyShredPrefs_data";

    Context mContext = this;

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    String HttpJSonURL;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        HttpJSonURL = intent.getExtras().getString("mystrdata");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences(MyShredPrefs, 0);
        HashMap<String, String> map= (HashMap<String, String>) s.getAll();

        //ti= Integer.parseInt(map.get("time_int"));
        ti=3000;

       try{
           SQLiteDataBaseBuild();
           SQLiteTableBuild();

           new StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass(ServMain2.this).execute();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reconnecting to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

    }

    private class StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {    //line No :65

        public Context context;
        String FinalJSonResult;

        public StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            HttpServiceClass httpServiceClass = new HttpServiceClass(HttpJSonURL);

            try {
                httpServiceClass.ExecutePostRequest();                 //line No :87
                if (httpServiceClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    FinalJSonResult = httpServiceClass.getResponse();
                    if (FinalJSonResult != null) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject(FinalJSonResult);
                            JSONArray response =JObject.getJSONArray("response");
                            for(int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject res = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String usr_id=res.getString("usr_id");
                                String phn_no=res.getString("phn_no");
                                String usr_name=res.getString("usr_name");

                                String usr_status= "NEW";

                                String SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder = "INSERT INTO "+ SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+" (usr_id,phn_no,usr_name,usr_status) VALUES('"+usr_id+"','"+phn_no+"','"+usr_name+"','"+usr_status+"');";

                                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ServMain2.this,"Load Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void SQLiteDataBaseBuild(){
        sqLiteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }

    public void SQLiteTableBuild(){

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+" ("+SQLiteHelper.T_USR_NO+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"+SQLiteHelper.T_USR_ID+" INTEGER(6),"+SQLiteHelper.T_PHN_NO+" VARCHAR2(15) , "+SQLiteHelper.T_USR_NAME+" TEXT, "+SQLiteHelper.T_USR_STATUS+" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL)");

    }

    public void DeletePreviousData(){
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+"");
    }

}
```

**Update**

I am Getting Error for Some time only... Not Always in 10 recordes.. Due to this error I am Missing 2 Records... after this error its working before error its working fine..

In a 10 times run its only failed to read Url for 2 or 3 time then again Its wokring fine
this is My Logcat...

```
AsyncTask #1 calls detatch()
I/System.out: @@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #2 calls detatch()
@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #3 calls detatch()
@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #4 calls detatch()
@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #5 calls detatch()
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:353)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:728)
at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
at my.api.service.HttpServiceClass.ExecutePostRequest(HttpServiceClass.java:85)
at my.api.service.ServMain2$StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass.doInBackground(ServMain2.java:87)
at my.api.service.ServMain2$StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass.doInBackground(ServMain2.java:65)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:353)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:728)
at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
at my.api.service.HttpServiceClass.ExecutePostRequest(HttpServiceClass.java:85)
at my.api.service.ServMain2$StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass.doInBackground(ServMain2.java:87)
at my.api.service.ServMain2$StoreJSonDataInToSQLiteClass.doInBackground(ServMain2.java:65)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
@@@@@@@null$$$$$$$@@@@@@@null$$$$$$$@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #3 calls detatch()
@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #4 calls detatch()
@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #5 calls detatch()
```

I have Added the Line Numbers... In my Code... like    **//line No :65**

**Update 1**

By Seeing My Log I can Clearly Say that URL is missing some times

```
@@@@@@@null$$$$$$$@@@@@@@null$$$$$$$@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #3 calls detatch()
@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #4 calls detatch()
@@@@@@@http://www......myservie/api_.......this is my live url$$$$$$$AsyncTask #5 calls detatch()
```

Because some times its Showing null and Some times its loading URL
and Some times error Due to null URL

Can Any one Suggest me on this Kind.. I need to url Like this only Because I am getting URL form Another Service

**Update 2**

In my JSON data Server Sends some time Empty JSON Array

It should be

```
{ 
"response": [ 
{ 
"usr_id": "1", 
"phn_no": "1234567890", 
"usr_name": "Demo" 
}, 
{ 
"usr_id": "2", 
"phn_no": "1234567890", 
"usr_name": "Demo" 
}, 
{ 
"usr_id": "3", 
"phn_no": "1234567890", 
"usr_name": "Demo" 
} 
] 
}
```

But Some times I am Getting Empty JSON Array like

```
{ 
"response": [] 
}
```

I have added  `if(response!= null && response .length()>0) {` to Check weather its empty or not.. But Still Same Issue.. Even I have added

```
catch (NullPointerException x) { 
// TODO Auto-generated catch block 
x.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

But still Not Resolved.. Can Any one Suggest me How to Handle that Empty String on this kind...

Answer (score 1):

use this code as it is.
I Think the issue is your response variable is empty try check on it like:

```
 try {
        JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject(FinalJSonResult);
        JSONArray response =JObject.getJSONArray("response");
        try {
            if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject res = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String usr_id = res.getString("usr_id");
                    String phn_no = res.getString("phn_no");
                    String usr_name = res.getString("usr_name");

                    String usr_status = "NEW";

                    String SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder = "INSERT INTO " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " (usr_id,phn_no,usr_name,usr_status) VALUES('" + usr_id + "','" + phn_no + "','" + usr_name + "','" + usr_status + "');";

                    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder);
                }
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException x) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

use this code it have a check `if(response!=null&&response .length()>0)`

Comment: thanks for Response user@irshad sheikh.. But its fails at 5th loop ,, same happen again.. as am thinking that URL is not loading Some times.. that error Seems like that.. But ... If possible suggest me how to fix it... How ever I have added your line but Same error

Comment: print a log of response.length() and see is it getting data in all time greater then 0 value.

Comment: I have added A log line `System.out.print("@@@@@@@ Working $$$$$$$");`.. But its similar to my previous Logcat.. insted of Url I am getting Working... I have added this inside the `if(response!=null&&response .length()>0)`.. But still I am getting Same error

Comment: the issue 'int java.lang.String.length()' is come from were your array is null and you try to get its length

Comment: Yes Now I got it ,, Can you Suggest me How to fix it,, Its problem with server side.... Please if you know Update your Answer I will mark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160903/discussion-between-irshad-sheikh-and-mln).